# ModelState.IsValid becomes false after adding anotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application If I add annotations to model properties then ModelState.IsValid becomes false.
If I remove all annotations then it becomes true.
when I add annotations, at that it annotations does work but it still goes to code even if fields are empty which should not happen.
I am using mvc4 razor.

My model where I have applied annotations

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HRMDatabaseLayer.Entities
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class EmployeeDetail
{
    public EmployeeDetail()
    {
        this.EmployeeContactDetails = new HashSet<EmployeeContactDetail>();
        this.EmployeeDepartments = new HashSet<EmployeeDepartment>();
        this.EmployeeEducations = new HashSet<EmployeeEducation>();
        this.EmployeeExperiances = new HashSet<EmployeeExperiance>();
        this.EmployeeFamilies = new HashSet<EmployeeFamily>();
        this.EmployeeLanguages = new HashSet<EmployeeLanguage>();
        this.EmployeeSkills = new HashSet<EmployeeSkill>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Id is Required")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is Required")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birth Date is Required")]
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeContactDetail> EmployeeContactDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDepartment> EmployeeDepartments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeEducation> EmployeeEducations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeExperiance> EmployeeExperiances { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeFamily> EmployeeFamilies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeLanguage> EmployeeLanguages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is my view

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee Id :
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => @model.Employee.EmployeeId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.Employee.EmployeeId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password : 
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.Employee.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.Employee.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value ="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
}
<br />
</div>
```

this is controller code where I am using ModelState.IsValid

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel empDetails)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ValidateUser(empDetails.Employee.EmployeeId, empDetails.Employee.Password))
            {
                Session["id"] = empRepository.GetEmpId(empDetails.Employee.EmployeeId);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(empDetails.Employee.EmployeeId, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User", new { area = "EmployeeDetails" });
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.LoginError = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
            }
        }
        empDetails.Employee.Password = string.Empty;
        return View("Index", empDetails);
    }
```

Comment: It might improve your question if you include the code with the annotations. Depending on what annotation you have use might force empty fields to hold a value, required for example.

Comment: You have used `LoginViewModel` in your controller action instead of `EmployeeDetail`. Try changing `public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel empDetails)` to `public ActionResult Login(EmployeeDetail empDetails)`

Comment: LoginViewModel is my view model where i have list of EmployeeDetail.

Comment: Try placing a debugger in your controller action and see whether all the properties have values. I think you need to use conditional validation in your controller action before checking `ModelState.IsValid`

Answer (score 1):

You should there is no editors or hidden fields for required properties Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Employee.Gender, Employee.DateOfBirth. So validation of this properties fail.

If you want to get from client only EmployeeId and Password, you should use another model that contains only this two properties.

Comment: Yes due to this only modelstate was false. But I have all properties in one model only & while doing login I cant have fields like firstname , lastname, etc.

Comment: It goes to code, but has flag ModelState.IsValid = false. It is typical for case that model is binded but validation attributes fails. You should not use your EmployeeDetail as viewmodel for Login.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the fields firstName, lastName, etc, then they shouldn't be part of the model that is sent to the view.  You should, instead of annotating and sending your domain model to the view, create a [View Model](http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications) containing only the properties you need for that view and put the data annotations there.

For example:
Remove all data annotations from the EmployeeDetail class, then

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Id is Required")]
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    //others you need for this view
}
```

Now strongly type your view to this model.  ModelState will now only care about the required properties in the view model, not any properties that are not needed in the view.

As for your comments about 'still hitting code', you probably just need to add

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

to your Web.Config, and you should take some time to dig deeper into server-side vs client-side validation.